# Text in place of zero result

Tags: t-sql

In my T-SQL select query, for each record, I want to return the field value (numeric) unless it is 0 (zero), where I want to return the text 'N/A'. What is the simplest way to accomplish this? I have tried using a CASE statement with CAST and CONVERT, but cannot get the result I need.

Comment: whats the error message you get when using cast/convert in a case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Field NUMERIC
SET @Field = 0

SELECT CASE WHEN cast(@Field as nvarchar(50)) = '0' then 'N/A' ELSE cast(@Field as nvarchar(50)) END
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I found your example the simplest to apply.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the same data type from your CASE statement otherwise in this case it is trying to convert toe "N/A" text value to a numeric type. Use the following, adjusting for your data types as needed:

```
SELECT CASE [MyFieldName] WHEN 0 THEN 'N/A' 
                          ELSE CAST([MyFieldName] AS VARCHAR(50)) 
       END
  ...
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct the ELSE CASE was a typo. It should have been ELSE CAST as you noted.

Answer (score 0):

If the field is not nullable:

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(fieldname,0),'N/A')
```

Otherwise:

```
CASE CONVERT(VARCHAR,fieldname) WHEN '0' THEN 'N/A' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,fieldname) END
```